# Re-declare string literal types

Tags: typescript

Given a string literal type:

```
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
```

Can I add more literals to the type after it has been declared? ie. without touching the declaration above (because it might be in a file that is not owned by me).

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

---

Things that don't work:

```
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
type Easing = Easing | 'uneasy'
```

or

```
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
type Easing |= 'uneasy'
```

or

```
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out" | 'uneasy';
```

All of these fail because of error "duplicate identifier 'Easing'."

---

If it's not allowed, why not? And why *is* it allowed to do something similar with enums? I don't see how they are any different.

```
enum Easing {
  EaseIn,
  EaseOut,
  EaseInOut
}

// works just fine
enum Easing {
  Uneasy = 3
}
```

Comment: You should probably give an indication of what underlying problem you're trying to solve. The specific thing you're asking for isn't the solution to any problem, but would be the cause of many!

Comment: It's a solution to the problem that `uneasy` is considered an invalid value for `Easing` even though it might very well be valid for what I'm doing. TS shouldn't pretend to know the code better than the people who wrote it.

Comment: IMO string literal types are really good at catching typo's but I feel like there should be a way to consciously tell typescript that "okay, I know what I'm doing so please just let me use this value"

Comment: There is: `as any`. But each time you do that, you're creating a hole for yourself to fall into in the future.

Comment: Not quite the same as actually adding "uneasy" to the list of supported string literals. By the way, why is declaration merging supported for enums but not string literals? Merged enums would break code in all the same ways.

Comment: enums exist at runtime, string literals aren't. With enums you can run throw the possible values at runtime.

Comment: @StevenLiekens I don't think enums can be merged in the sense of adding further allowed values. Rather you can merge a namespace with an enum so you can add "static members" such as functions, typically operations on the enum type.

Comment: They can: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Easing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20EaseIn%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20EaseOut%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20EaseInOut%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20works%20just%20fine%0D%0Aenum%20Easing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Uneasy%20%3D%203%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20member%20in%20Easing)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20document.write(member%20%2B%20'%3Cbr%3E')%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: That's interesting! It's also true that you can add extra members to an interface, which means that a separate module implementing the plain version of that interface will now be "breaking" your code by not fully implementing the augmented version. So it seems inconsistent that this kind of hackery (allowed with many other things) is not allowed with string literal types.

Comment: Really the problem is not to do with string literal type specifically. It's rather the fact that declaration merging on `type` aliases is not supported. Theoretically it could be interpreted as the union of the two declarations: `decl1 | decl2` so your augmentation would just say `type Easing = 'uneasy'` and that would be or-ed with the original.

Comment: So I guess one solution is to leave the `Easing` type alone and instead create overloads for all usages of `Easing`. (One overload for every `uneasy` string)

Comment: example: `function addClassName(el: HTMLElement, a: Easing) {}` would have at least one overload `function addClassName(el: HTMLElement, a: 'uneasy') {}`

Answer (score 0):

If you could have done that it would create problems, consider the following:

```
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
function addClassName(el: HTMLElement, a: Easing) {
    el.className += " " + a;
}
```

So that was part of a different file, and who ever wrote that only expects to handle the 3 specific values which are defined by `Easing`.
By changing that you might break that code.

What you can do in your file is:

```
type Easing2 = Easing | "uneasy";
```

Then use that instead of `Easing`.

Comment: In that example, the code only expects `Easing` values but it is not guarded against other values.

    `addClassName(el, 'uneasy' as string as Easing);`

look, no TS error.

It's already possible to pass undefined values so I don't agree that my change breaks code that does not guard against them.

Comment: (Forgive me if I misunderstood what the `as` operator does and my previous comment is wrong)

Comment: You can obviously bypass the compiler, you can also just use `as any` on everything, but then what's the point of using typescript? The compiler will not let you pass other values, if you decide not to listen then your code may break.